# Why is it keep saying undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Two models are created....and the associations are also mentioned in models.

first model is Item and second model is Activity.

Item model code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :activities
end
```

Activity Model code:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
end
```

i can show every item with the help of the link.....now i want to an activity to that specific item and for that purpose i have created a controller which is "Activities" and then i have written the code in it which is as follow:

Activities Model Code:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def create
    @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    @activity = @item.activities.create(activity_params)
    redirect_to items_path(@item)
  end

  private
    def activity_params
      params.require(:activity).permit(:task)
    end
end
```

the code for the show.html.erb for the items contorller is as follow:

Show.html.erb(Items_controller) Code:

```
<h1>Show Goal</h1>

<p>
  <strong>Goal: </strong>
  <%= @item.goal %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Description: </strong>
  <%= @item.description %>
</p>

<h2>Activity</h2>
<% @items.activities.each do |activity| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Activity:</strong>
    <%= activity.task %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<h2>Add a Activity:</h2>
<%= form_for([@item, @item.activities.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :Task %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :task %>
  </p>
    <%= f.submit "Add Activity"%>
  </p>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(@item) %>
<%= link_to  "Back" , items_path %>
```

The error comes from this line and it says "undefined method `activities' for nil:NilClass"

```
<% @items.activities.each do |activity| %>
```

Migration code for the "Activity" Model

Migration for Activity model Code:

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :activities do |t|
      t.string :task


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now i can not figure out where is this error coming from "undefined method `activities' for nil:NilClass"....????????

Comment: `<% @item.activities.each do |activity| %>` - It should  be `@item` instead of `@items`

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'activities.item_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`item_id` = 1......Now this error pops up from the same line....?????

Comment: Have you not added `item_id` column to `activities` table ? `item_id` will be foreign key to establish the association between `Item` and `Activity`.

Comment: Nope i have'nt done anything like that...any guide line????

Comment: Can you add your `db/schema.rb` ?   Steps to create `item_id` for `activities` : `rails g migration AddItemReferenceToActivity item:references` , and then run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

`@items` is nil because you define only `@item`

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'activities.item_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`item_id` = 1......Now this error pops up from the same line....???????

Answer (score 1):

Error says `"undefined method activities' for nil:NilClass"` 
and which is right as well `@items` is *nil*

Go back to controller its @item, there is a typo

Additionally check your migration file, in migration file for `Activity` there should be a foreign key for Item `item_id`, if no drop that migration using

`rake db:migrate:down VERSION=migration number`

and edit the file and re run the `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'activities.item_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`item_id` = 1......Now this error pops up from the same line....???????

Comment: @Thinkerzz Check your migration file, in migration file for `Activity` there should be a foreign key for Item `item_id`, if no drop that migration using `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=migration number` and edit the file and re run the `rake db:migrate`.  Let us know if issue was with migration file.

Comment: it was the migration file but i created the new migration and then i was able to work with it. but thanks to all for the help....appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below line to

```
<% @items.activities.each do |activity| %>
```

to

```
<% @item.activities.each do |activity| %>
```

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'activities.item_id' in 'where clause': SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities` WHERE `activities`.`item_id` = 1......now this error pops up.

Comment: from the same line.

Comment: You need to create a migration to add an item_id column, run this on the command line: rails g migration add_item_id_to_activities item_id:integer (edited for spelling)

Answer (score 0):

You need create a migration to add references for `item` to `activity`

`rails g migration AddItemToActivities item:references`

Then your file should look like this:

```
class AddItemToActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :activities, :item, index: true
  end
end
```

Then you can easily loop by referencing this way:

```
<% @item.activities.each do |activity| %>
...
```